# Spring Boot Logout then Login Redirects to Wrong URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, logout

So I've added a new controller method that signs the User out without the logout confirmation, seen below:

```
    public String quickLogout (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect: /login?logout";
    }
```

This works as expected, and signs the user out, but whenever this is called, and I try signing back in, I get directed to this URL: `http://localhost:8080/%20/login?logout`

It should be directing it to: `http://localhost:8080/`

The normal logout with confirmation then login does not have this error, and the first sign in when the application starts does not have it either. I'm using the basic Spring Security Login, so I'm uncertain why it's doing this.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to redirect to ‘/‘ after logout? Instead of “ return "redirect: /login?logout";” you should return "redirect: /";

Comment: Now when trying to log in after the logout method is called, I get directed to `http://localhost:8080/%20/`

Comment: Aha, you shall have no space after  ‘redirect:’, so just redirect:/

Comment: That was absolutely the issue. I can get why it's set up that way, but I still don't like it. 

Appreciate the quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to Bob Tang in the comments: Yes, all whitespace is used in the redirect so instead of:

```
return "redirect: /login?logout";
```

Use:

```
return "redirect:/login?logout";
```

The space between the colon and first forward slash is otherwise used, messing up navigation.